# where should I put the jar file?

Tags: java, classpath

If I create a java program in java editor like notepad++ and I need to some external jar file for running this program then where should I put it for running this program.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how or where you create the program. Required jars should be on the classpath.
If you are using command line to execute the program you can use

```
java -classpath pathOfRequiredJars PathToClass
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to add all your `.jar` libraries inside a subfolder of the project folder, like `MyProject\lib`. It doesn't matter that you use one editor or another, you will have to specify the `classpath` to these required `jars` when running your project.

Comment: This doesn't answer the Question.